# ffmpeg split video H264 stutters on Windows Media Player

Tags: video, ffmpeg, windows-media-player

I am converting and splitting wmv and mp4 into new mp4 files.  I am using ffmpeg to do the conversion with simply:
ffmpeg -i inputfile.wmv -vcodec libx264 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:15 outputfile.mp4

So when I create my split video it plays fine on other video players, like VLC, but stutters when initially playing on Windows Media Player and even shows a blank screen for a moment and then after about 5 seconds, the video will play normally. If I then select play again without reloading, Windows Media Player will play the video fine, with no stuttering.

If I REMOVE the start parameter when doing the conversion, then the resulting video will play without issues on all my players, INCLUDING Windows Media Player.

I have tried changing the frame rate, the bit rate and altered different optimization options mentioned here - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

I need the split video to play on Windows machines on Windows Media Player and on the web streamed using the video element.  This is why I chose H264 codec and MP4.

Has anyone had issues playing ffmpeg split videos using H264 codec with Windows Media Player?  I am using the latest version of ffmpeg. Anyone have any other suggestions on any different settings I could try to adjust?

Thanks

Comment: WMP is known to have trouble with edit lists in MP4. So try `ffmpeg -i inputfile.wmv -vcodec libx264 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:15 -use_editlist 0 outputfile.mp4`

Comment: The use_editlist option unfortunately did not seem to help.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It seems setting the Keyframe distance or GOP lower helps a lot when splitting.  Adding a force of key frames did not do anything (-force_key_frames), but setting the keyframe interval (GOP length) -g to 50 and -keyint_min to 20 seems to have solved the issue with Windows Media Player.